# How do I delete duplicate values in one row of a 2D Numpy array, and also delete the corresponding value in the other row as well?

Tags: python, numpy

Say that I have a 2D numpy array that looks like this

```
x = np.array( [[ 3 , 4, 2 ,4, 7, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 7 ], [ 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] ])
print(x)

>[[ 3  4  2  4  7  9  7  5  2  1  7]
> [11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1]]
```

I want to delete duplicate numbers in the first row, and delete the corresponding number in the 2nd row. The number that does Not get deleted is the biggest one (from the 2nd row).

Here's what I want the output to look like.

```
>[[ 3  4  2  7  9  5  1  ]
> [11 10  9  7  6  4   2  ]]
```

All duplicates from row 1 have been deleted, as well as the corresponding value in row 2. The value that remains is always the biggest value in row 2.

If it helps, we can assume row 2 is always sorted in descending order like it is above.

Comment: You're missing a pair of values from your setup to your output.  The last `8, 1` should also be included

Comment: fixed, I changed that last 8 to be a 7 to include cases where there are three duplicates but forgot to update the first line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_index=True`:

```
_, idx = np.unique(x[0], return_index=1)
x[:, np.sort(idx)]
```

```
array([[ 3,  4,  2,  7,  9,  5,  1],
       [11, 10,  9,  7,  6,  4,  2]])
```